# Retrieving 16-bit big endian value from byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, endianness

I have an unsigned 16-bit integer in big endian byte order: 0x01f1 but they are in a byte array as follows:

```
    Array
  [0]  0x01
  [1]  0xf1
```

How do I "join" Array[0] with Array[1] such that I could have my value of 0x01f1 back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [shift and bitwise operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to combine the two array elements as follows:

```
byte[] array = new byte[] { 0x01, 0xF1 };

int result = (array[0] << 8) | array[1];
// result == 0x01F1
```

Answer (score 0):

use left shift operator as follows:

```
int myNum = a[0];
myNum = (myNum<<8);
myNum = myNum | a[1];
```